# Как правильно реализовать Last-Modified?

Tags: php, nginx, apache, http

При первоначально загрузке страницы, в заголовке возвращаю дату Last-Modified.
При следующих запросах к странице, проверяю, нет ли в запросе If-Modified-Since.
Если есть, получаю из БД Last-Modified и сравниваю с If-Modified-Since.

Вопрос, рационально ли делать запрос к БД? Так как на это тратятся ресурсы.
Возможно правильным будет хранить Last-Modified в какух и от туда забирать данные для сравнения?

Но возможно я не так понял принцип работы. Подскажите. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Запрос с If-Modified-Since предполагает, что ответ будет отправлен только в случае, если содержимое этого ответа изменилось после указанной даты. То есть надо сравнить дату из заголовка и дату изменения того, что вы отдаёте. Кука хранится на стороне клиента, и не меняется, когда вы меняете что-то на стороне сервера. В куке не будет актуальной даты обновления содержимого вашей страницы. Поэтому вам надо делать запрос в базу.

Подход с Last-Modified/If-Modified-Since поможет сэкономить время и другие ресурсы клиенту, если он хранит кэш вашего ответа. Это хорошо работает со статикой. Но обратите внимание, что если речь идёт о веб-страницах, то там могут меняться самые разные части. Например, статья в базе данных не поменялась, а html для её оформления, который хранится не в базе, а в файле шаблона, поменялся.

Реализуйте поддержку этих заголовков, если ясно понимаете, какой профит это вам принесёт. Не делайте это просто потому, что можете.